# Rails App Sending contact email with SendGrid using Ubuntu on DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, ubuntu-14.04, sendgrid

Trying to send a message out to an address when someone completes a form. But I'm getting an error:

```
Errno::ECONNREFUSED in SupportrequestsController#create
Connection refused - connect(2) for "smtp.sendgrid.net" port 587

@supportrequest = Supportrequest.new(params[:supportrequest])

     if @supportrequest.save  <---GETTING ERROR HERE
        HydraNotifier.send_support_email(@supportrequest).deliver
        flash.now[:error] = nil
        redirect_to( contact_path, :notice => 'email sent')
```

I'm using:
Rails 4.2.5.1
ruby 2.2.3p173

## Gemfile:

gem 'mail_form', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.1'
gem 'sendgrid'

Here is my SMTP settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp  
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    :port => 587,
    :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USER'],
    :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASS'],
    :domain => "mydomain.com",
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: Most likely DigitalOcean is blocking SMTP ports. Contact support there and ask them to remove the block, or switch to sending via HTTPS.

Comment: I talked with DigitalOcean and SendGrid. Neither of them had solutions for me. But for whatever reason it started working today.